# How many times must the GeoCoordinateWatcher fire?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, gps, windows-phone-7.1, location-based-service

My Wp7 (Mango) app needs to know the location of the user in order to search for the nearest object in the database. But I want to display the result on the welcome screen, so I need my location ASAP. I've written a code that starts the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` (on high precision and minimal threshold), and on the first firing it stops it, and sends the location to the webservice, which returns the object in question.

After I tested it, I went to present it, to the other side of the town. I started it and for everyone's amusement it showed a completely wrong result - I know why: it still thought I was at home!

How long does it take for the GPS to update? **How will I know that I finally got my current location? How many times should I allow the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` to fire before stopping it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the answer here:

http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/geo-location-on-wp7-dont-trust-first.html

Basically, keep asking for updates until one is in the range from when you started requesting them.

```
in PositionChanged

if ( (DateTime.Now - e.Position.TimeStamp.DateTime) < LocationTimeout)
  {
         //recent enough.
  }
```

Comment: @Ku6opr just had this exact issue yesterday, so the issue was on the tip of my tongue :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `StatusChanged` event for handling such as old user location (at home). When device status is ready - you have current location (but it can be inaccurate). So, use `HorizontalAccuracy` if you need high precision position ;)

Comment: yeah but the first ( few) StatusChanged events will still contain the OLD location! How will I know it has updated?